# Put default Git merge in TFS

Tags: git, tfs, diff

I recently switched to command-line git for my personal projects.

I have used 3-way merge tools in the past and found them to be still a pain.

I really like the way CLI git handles merge file, it dumps both version into the file with <<<<  and >>>>. How do i get that functionality for TFS which I am required to use at work?

Comment: +1: I don't use TFS, but it's nice to see a question asking how to *keep* Git's conflict resolution format, instead of how to replace it with a merge tool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that

> Git source control has a build-in merging behavior that I want to replicate in TFS.

is going to be a possibility.

The ***git merge*** functionality is tied to the git source control, meaning that git merge will not merge two untracked files. This is subtly different from ***git diff*** which does allow for the comparison of two untracked files.

As an alternative, you may want to consider a workflow that uses [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs). The following is [a helpful article on this workflow](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/15/git-tfs-where-have-you-been-all-my-life/).

Answer (score 3):

I don't have experience with what you are using, yet this might be helpful for you:
Navigate in VS to "Tools->Options...->Source Control->Visual studio Team foundation server ->Configure User Tools.." & add a new line (Extension = `.*`, operation = `merge` Command =  the path to your tool).
Placing the arguments so that if fits to your needs should be possible. I used this to make use of my merge-tool of choice.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I am looking for. To be specific, Git source control has a build-in merging behavior that I want to replicate in TFS.